# Grails belongsTo relationship fails on save due to null id

Tags: java, hibernate, grails

I'm having some trouble with my GORM relationship management. Basically there are 4 domain classes that are in the scope of this question. A `House` is a restaurant which has multiple `Queue`, each of which has multiple `Ticket`. The tickets belong to a `Customer`.

The main problem is that when I create a `Ticket` with a `Customer` and a `Queue` instance hibernate complains that `customer_ID` is `null`. The `Ticket` domain class looks like this:

```
class Ticket implements Comparable<Ticket> {
    int number;
    boolean isValid;

    static belongsTo = [customer: Customer, queue: Queue]

    public Ticket(Customer customer, Queue queue,int number){
        println "Create ticket, customer: ${customer}, queue:${queue}, number:${number}";
        customer = customer;
        queue = queue;
        number = number;
        isValid = true;
    }
}
```

The error is in one controller class where I create the `Ticket` and save it.

```
//c and q are Customer and Queue instances that have passed null check
Ticket t = new Ticket(c, q, 10);//In the constructor I see the Customer and Queue instances are not null indeed
t.save(flush: true);
if (t.hasErrors()) {
    log.error t.errors;
    return;
}
```

The error is an empty `Customer_ID` which I don't quite understand. I have passed the customer and queue into the `Ticket` constructor but why Grails doesn't seem to match the id when I save it? I've verified that customer id is generated successfully. Please point me to the mistake I've made in the GORM settings.

`Message: NULL not allowed for column "CUSTOMER_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into ticket (id, version, customer_id, is_valid, number, queue_id) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-176]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is literally the shadowing problem of the same name of arguments & fields. Just change your constructor like this:

```
class Ticket implements Comparable<Ticket> {
    int number;
    boolean isValid;

    static belongsTo = [customer: Customer, queue: Queue]

    public Ticket(Customer customer, Queue queue, int number) {
        println "Create ticket, customer: ${customer}, queue:${queue}, number:${number}";
        this.customer = customer;
        this.queue = queue;
        this.number = number;
        this.isValid = true;
    }
}
```

You have to use `this` keyword inside the constructor because the domain fields `customer` and `queue` and other is shodowed by the constructor parameter.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Because of `customer = customer` you are assigning the value of constructor argument to itself instead you should be doing `this.customer = customer` (same for all others)

Comment: Thank you so much! Correct me if I'm wrong but I think this worked before. Care to elaborate what you mean by "old Java syntax" please?

Comment: :-) By "old Java syntax" I meant to write that it's the basic Java problem a developer may encounter. Did that solved your problem?

Comment: Solved like a spark. Thanks!

Comment: Grails implements constructors by default. It's not a good idea create a new one, when managing relations, and cascades in domains. For instance the relation belongsTo in a has many relation in the other side, should be create by the addTo and removeFrom methods.